# Unity3D Solar System Proprieties

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this question about Unity3D objects and their proprieties. I've made this scenery that has several prefabs (stars) generated automatically that basically represent a solar system in the galactic map. My noob question is, how can I associate to each of these objects a random number of planets that show up in the UI when I click them. I was thinking about using text files with the names of the systems/planets, but from this on I am stuck. Should I use a database where the game will store planets/ships/other objects and update them as the game progresses? What would be the best approach for this problem? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome fellow Unity programmer!  I think your question is a little broad and asking for "best" somewhat subject to opinion.  Try looking over at [gamedev](http://www.gamedev.net/) for there you will find some brilliant articles; forums and other resources.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll check out Gamedev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases might be overkill.  I'm currently using MongoDB with the Eve REST interface and I use the following code to fetch my data for display Unity:

```
WWW request = new WWW(url);
while(!request.isDone)
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject(request.text);
```

However, the only reason I elected to use this configuration is because of the size of my data (hundreds of thousands of data points) and I only access what I need this way.  Unless your data is persistent and very large, this kind of set up can get out of control quickly.

To start, you could look into using [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to store whatever data you need.

Using `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PlanetName",100)`, you set the value for that planet and it would be accessible to the game later via `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PlanetName")`

Generally, when you're setting a value for the player's progression, you can use PlayerPrefs.  Since you'll be modifying and accessing this information throughout the game, I think this might be a good option for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :)
Problem is I have a bunch of players, all moving ships and such. I'm not sure what would be best for the game at this point.

Comment: How are your games configured?  How many players are in a match?  What are you using for online play?

Comment: I'm a rookie at Unity, I'm not planning any multiplayer right now. I'm just trying to figure out how to handle data in the game.